# Swift - After loading subview from xib to UIScrollView, scroll is not working and subview is going out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a xib file of name View1.xib which contain some stack views containing certain set of buttons.

[View1.xib UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcMf3.png)

2. Im having a coco touch class of type UIView for loading the Nib named View1. Also I have made it as owner of the previous xib. Below is the code I'm using to load the view:

   ```
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       commitInit()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       commitInit()
   }

   private func commitInit() {
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("View1", owner: self, options: nil)

       containerView.frame = self.bounds
       containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
       addSubview(containerView)
   }
   ```
3. Now in the storyboard I included the scrollview and a sub UIView under it. I have defined the Subview type as View1.

[ScrollView in main storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJIpH.png)

4. Also I have defined proper constraints for the Views making it equal height and width as the Parent ScrollView.

[Scrollview constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZp15.png)

5. Also find the scrollview properties defined as below:

[ScrollView Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBZq0.png)

6. This is how the screen looks like on emulator :

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksKu5.png)

Now when I'm running the project I'm getting the screen but I'm unable to scroll through the view included. Due to this some elements on top and bottom becomes hidden (Out of bounds) and I'm unable to scroll as well. Am I  doing anything wrong? Please help me out.

Note - I'm very new to swift, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't shout. It doesn't make a difference to the people you are asking the question to. It may even make people not approach it even.

Answer (score 1):

Your `newView` can't flow out of `scrollView`'s bound, Because it has same height with your `scrollView`. But your `newView`'s content flows out of `newView`'s bounds.(You can see if you put your `newView` out of scrollView with same height and set it a `backgroundColor` or set `clipToBounds` property `true`) That's why you can't scroll.

To Sove This, you should find another source for your `newView`'s `height`(Maybe a constant value or its subview's heihgt or `safeArea.heihgt` . This is your choice)

Answer (score 0):

1. For subview add 
    yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, then left, right, top, bottom constraint programatically then add subview.
2. For scroll view set the height constraint for inner view with the scroll view. Make the outlet of that constraint and then set dynamic height of the scrollview outlet.

Comment: I didn't understand some points:  Point 1. So i should declare containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false in the UIView class?  Point 2: For the UIView under scroll view I have already made it to be equal width and height as superview (UIScrollView). What exactly you mean by setting dynamic height of the scrollview outlet? Please do let me know. Thanks